# Is it possible to add two different background images when sliverAppBar collapsed and when it's expanded in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

[image: Background image for collapsed AppBar]

Hi, everyone! I want to add two different images for SliverAppBar. One for when app bar collapsed and one for expanded app bar. In the above image for collapsed app bar. And below image for expanded app bar.
[image: Background image for expanded SliverAppBar]

How can I achieve that? And how I can animate images to transfer smoothly from expanded to collapsed and reversely? Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @krumpli I couldn't add image for collapsed SliverAppBar. I've tried with Stack instead of FlexibleSpaceBar. In this case image is seems to shown in collapsed mode also, but I'm not able to change my background image

Comment: Still, you need to show some code